# C Programming , Changing String Value in function without passing the size as parameter

Tags: c, string, function, char, sizeof

i have a question, i know the following implementation works correctly :

```
  void editMessage(char* message , int sizeOfMessage){
    char newMessage[] = "modified";

    printf("size of message is %lu \n",sizeof(message));
    printf("size of new message is %lu \n",sizeof(newMessage));

    if (sizeof(newMessage) <= sizeOfMessage) {

        for (int i=0 ; i < sizeof(newMessage); i++) {

            message[i] = newMessage[i];

        }

    } else {
        printf("size of new message is too big\n");
    }

}

int main() {

    char randMessage[] = "original message";
    editMessage(randMessage,sizeof(randMessage));
    printf("the value of randMessage after function call is %s \n",randMessage);
    return 0;
}
```

but if i want to change the string value in function without passing the size of pointer, is it possible? if yes , how? if not , why not?

i mean i am looking to change above editMessage Function something like this :

```
  void editMessage(char* message){
    char newMessage[] = "modified";

    printf("size of message is %lu \n",sizeof(message));
    printf("size of new message is %lu \n",sizeof(newMessage));

    if (sizeof(newMessage) <= sizeOf(message)) {

        for (int i=0 ; i < sizeOf(message); i++) {

            message[i] = newMessage[i];

        }

    } else {
        printf("size of new message is too big\n");
    }

}
```

and the call in the main like this

```
editMessage(randMessage);
```

why this is not working , could one please explain in details , and then i would accept his response?
Thanks!

Comment: `sizeof(message)` is the *size of the pointer*, not the size of the object it points to.

Comment: Use `strlen` to get the *length* of a string.

Comment: @user3001566  At least the first function you showed is incorrect and does not make sense.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeOf(message)` will not work. `sizeOf(message)` will give the size of the variable `message`, and since originally `message` is a pointer you will get the size of a pointer.

---

Since it is a `NUL` terminated string, you can get the length of the string by using `strlen()` and use that in your function.

---

So, your code should look something like this,

```
  void editMessage(char* message){
    char newMessage[] = "modified";
    int size = strlen(message);

    printf("size of message is %d \n", size);
    printf("size of new message is %lu \n",sizeof(newMessage));

    if (sizeof(newMessage) <= size) {

        for (int i=0 ; i < size; i++) {

            message[i] = newMessage[i];

        }

    } else {
        printf("size of new message is too big\n");
    }

}
```

---

For an array of `char` which is not terminated by `NUL`, there is no way to find out the length other then sending the length of the array of `char` as a parameter.

Therefore, in the calling function you need to keep track of the number of `char`s you are writing in the array (to know the length).

*Notice I am not saying **string** because an array of `char` becomes a **string** only when it is terminated by a `NUL` character.*

---

**NOTE:**

Use the standard definition of `main()`

```
int main(void) //if no command line arguments.
```

Comment: what if the charachter array will not terminated by null? then if i can't use strlen what is the solution? if you could explain this condition and add it to your answer then i would accept your post as answer of this thread, Thanks

Comment: @user3001566, there you go.. :)

Comment: regard your code `int size = strlen(message);` I have tried your code in the Xcode , and i got compile and warning error , here are the 2 warnings , can you please correct your code? /Users/XXX/test/test/main.c:59:17: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' also the second error is /Users/XXX/test/test/main.c:59:17: Implicitly declaring library function 'strlen' with type 'unsigned long (const char *)' I temprorly uncheck your answer as not accepted , until you fix it, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> if i want to change the string value in function without passing the size of pointer, is it possible? if yes , how? if not , why not?

You can determine the length of the input message via the `strlen()` function.  Supposing that you stipulate that the function works as intended only for properly null-terminated strings, it is reasonable for it to assume that the array containing the string is long enough to accommodate it, including the terminator.  Thus, to some extent you could `strlen(message) + 1` in place of the original's `sizeOfMessage`.

***However***, that is more limiting than the original function, because the array containing the string could be larger than the string requires.  If you use the length of the input string to limit the length of the replacement string, then you can never make use of any such excess capacity.  Consider:

```
int main() {
    char randMessage[1024] = "";
     /*
      * sizeof(randMessage) is 1024, but strlen(randMessage) is 0.  Which do
      * you prefer as the limit on the size of the message that editMessage()
      * can insert?
      */
    editMessage(randMessage, sizeof(randMessage));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C,

`void func(char message[])` becomes `void func(char *message)`. So, when you do a `sizeof(message)` in the called function, it will only return the size of the pointer. In "C" arrays are not passed by values.

If you are sure, your character array will always be null terminated, you use `strlen` to get it's length.

Comment: what if the charachter array will not terminated by null? then if i can't use strlen what is the solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `strlen` to get the length of the input string.

BTW: Notice this part of your code:

```
if (sizeof(newMessage) <= sizeOfMessage) {

    for (int i=0 ; i < sizeOfMessage; i++) {

        message[i] = newMessage[i];
```

If `sizeof(newMessage)` is 9 and `sizeOfMessage` is 100 you will access `newMessage[9]` to `newMessage[99]` which is outside the array.